# How to convert that .txt to file to .dat file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file with employees information with delimiter '|' . How to convert that .txt to file to .dat file in python

Answer (score 1):

That can be done this way:

```py
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    r = f.read()
with open('file.dat','w') as f:
    f.write(r)
```

I recommend using your resources like google before asking because I bet there are plenty of other good answers out there.
You did not specify if you wished to convert the extension or translate the content. If you wish to translate the content find a lib that can do it. ;)

Comment: If all you're doing is reading and writing the file then wouldn't you be better off just copying it or renaming it?

Comment: @Sayse they asked to do it in python, but realistically yes.